# How do we calculate the probabillity of a OR b OR c Or d Or e

Tags: probability

We all know the formula for the probability of a or b happening.  It is p(a or b ) = p(a) + p(b).  We also all know (maybe) the theorem for p(a or b or c).  (It's on google lol.)  It is p(a or b or c) = p(a) + p(b)  + p

(c) - p(a and b) - p(b and c) - p(a and c) + p(a and b and c).

A more important question that I am trying to figure out is the formula for the p(a or b or c or d or e)  =

Better yet, its there a theorem that we can use to calculate the p(a or b or c or d or e or f ...)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) if that is what you are looking at. More formally, in probability space $(\Omega, \boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, \mathbb P) ,$ if $A_i\in\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A}, ~i\in\{1, \cdots, n\}, ~n\in\mathbb N, $ then

$$\mathbb P\left[\cup_{1\leq i\leq n} A_i\right]= \sum_{1\leq i\leq n} \mathbb P[A_i] -\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n} P[A_iA_j]+\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq n} \mathbb P[A_iA_jA_k]-\cdots+(-1)^n\mathbb P[A_1A_2\cdots A_n].$$ This can be easily shown based on an argument of induction.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for $P(A\lor B)$ you give is incorrect and is only correct if $A$ and $B$ happen to be disjoint events. The general formula is $P(A\lor B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\land B)$, the intuition for this formula being that when you add up $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, you are double counting the states that are part of both $A$ and $B$, hence the need to subtract it out. The formula for $P(A\lor B\lor C)$ works the same way. First, add up $P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$. You will have double counted the states that are part of both $A$ and $B$, part of both $B$ and $C$, or part of both $C$ and $A$. No matter, we just subtract those out. But by doing this subtraction, we will have over-adjusted for states that below to the intersection of all three $A$ and $B$ and $C$, so we need to add this intersection of all three back. Putting this all together gives the formula
$$P(A\lor B\lor C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\land B) - P(B\land C) - P(A\land C) + P(A\land B\land C)$$
The generalization of this formula is a bit tedious and tricky to write down into a concise formula, but conceptually is no difficult than the argument I have given above. The resulting formula is known as the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), and it implies that
$$P\left(\bigvee_{i=1}^N A_i \right) = \sum_{k=1}^N (-1)^{n-k} \sum_{S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,N\}} P\left(\bigwedge_{s\in S} A_s\right)$$